# Allow FAPI checkboxes to specify some options as disabled

Tags: forms, 8

I want to disable a single checkbox in a `checkboxes` FAPI element.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\fapi_example\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class SimpleForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * Build the simple form.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['checboxes'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#options' => [
        'A' => $this->t('A'), 
        'B' => $this->t('B'),
        //I want C allway check and disable.
        'C' => $this->t('C'),
        'D' => $this->t('D'),
      ],
      '#default_value' => array('C'),
      //Follow topic https://www.drupal.org/node/284917. But don't work
      //'#disabled_values' => array('C'),
      '#title' => $this->t('Title Checkboxes'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Getter method for Form ID.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'form_checkboxes';
  }

  /**
   * Implements a form submit handler.
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

}
```

I try to follow this [topic](https://www.drupal.org/node/284917) but its not working (8.1.x), and tried to search in google but it just 
solve in [Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/832/how-can-i-disable-a-single-checkbox-in-a-checkboxes-fapi-element). So How can I disable a single checkbox in a 'checkboxes' FAPI element?

Comment: Please provide the code you've come up with that isn't working. That will help others answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a way. Add option process in define form type.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\fapi_example\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class SimpleForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * Build the simple form.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['checboxes'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#options' => [
        'A' => $this->t('A'), 
        'B' => $this->t('B'),
        //I want C allways check and disable.
        'C' => $this->t('C'),
        'D' => $this->t('D'),
      ],
      //Add options process
      '#process' => [
        array($this, 'processCheckboxes'),
      ],
      '#default_value' => array('C'),
      //Follow topic https://www.drupal.org/node/284917. But don't work
      //'#disabled_values' => array('C'),
      '#title' => $this->t('Title Checkboxes'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Process checkboxes
   */
  public static function processCheckboxes(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    $value = is_array($element['#value']) ? $element['#value'] : array();
    $element['#tree'] = TRUE;
    if (count($element['#options']) > 0) {
      if (!isset($element['#default_value']) || $element['#default_value'] == 0) {
        $element['#default_value'] = array();
      }
      $weight = 0;
      foreach ($element['#options'] as $key => $choice) {
        if ($key === 0) {
          $key = '0';
        }
        $weight += 0.001;

        $element += array($key => array());
        $element[$key] += array(
          '#type' => 'checkbox',
          '#title' => $choice,
          '#return_value' => $key,
          '#default_value' => isset($value[$key]) ? $key : NULL,
          '#attributes' => $element['#attributes'],
          '#ajax' => isset($element['#ajax']) ? $element['#ajax'] : NULL,
          '#error_no_message' => TRUE,
          '#weight' => $weight,
        );

        if ($key == 'C') {
          $element[$key]['#disabled'] = TRUE;
          $element[$key]['#default_value'] = $key;
        }
      }
    }
    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * Getter method for Form ID.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'form_checkboxes';
  }

  /**
   * Implements a form submit handler.
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

}
```

It's working but i think FAPI allow options disable some value is better.