# How to disable the first option of select form element

Tags: 8, forms

I created a custom module that contains a form with select element
I tried to disable the first option like this, but failed to get it work

```
'#options' => $terms,
                '#empty_option' => '- Select category -',
                '#empty_value' => 'none',
                '#disabled_values' => array('none'),
```

How could this be achieved without removing the option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a contrib module that can help: [Form Options Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_options_attributes)

> This module adds the ability to specify attributes for individual
>   options on Drupal Form API elements of the types: select, checkboxes,
>   and radios.

Also Jaime Calvo's answer about writing:

```
['#options']['my disabled option'] = [];
```

Doesn't really create a disabled option, but an empty `optgroup`.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal by default doesn't allow for this, so you'll need to do two things:

1. Override theme_select()
2. Create your own callback the create the options
3. Change the way you define your select options in your form definition

Overriding theme_select():

```
function THEME_select($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-select'));

  return '<select' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . custom_form_select_options($element) . '</select>';
}
```

Create your own callback the create the options:

```
function custom_form_select_options($element, $choices = NULL) {
  if (!isset($choices)) {
    $choices = $element['#options'];
  }
  // array_key_exists() accommodates the rare event where $element['#value'] is NULL.
  // isset() fails in this situation.
  $value_valid = isset($element['#value']) || array_key_exists('#value', $element);
  $value_is_array = $value_valid && is_array($element['#value']);
  $options = '';
  foreach ($choices as $key => $choice) {
    if (is_array($choice) && !isset($choice['data'])) {
      $options .= '<optgroup label="' . check_plain($key) . '">';
      $options .= form_select_options($element, $choice);
      $options .= '</optgroup>';
    }
    elseif (is_object($choice)) {
      $options .= form_select_options($element, $choice->option);
    }
    else {
      $key = (string) $key;
      if ($value_valid && (!$value_is_array && (string) $element['#value'] === $key || ($value_is_array && in_array($key, $element['#value'])))) {
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
      }
      else {
        $selected = '';
      }
      $options .= '<option value="' . check_plain($key) . '"' . $selected;
      if(is_array($choice) && isset($choice['disabled']) && $choice['disabled'])
      {
          $options .= ' disabled';
      }
      $choice = is_array($choice) && isset($choice['data']) ? $choice['data'] : $choice;
      $options .= '>' . check_plain($choice) . '</option>';
    }
  }
  return $options;
}
```

Change the way you define your select options in your form definition. Turn the option into an array with two keys:

1. data: The display value of the element
2. disabled: A boolean indicating whether to disable the element

Example:

```
$form['select'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Pick something'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array(
    'yes' => array('data' => t('Yes'), 'disabled' => TRUE),
    'no' => t('No'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: The function THEME_select() and  THEME_form_select_options() override by theme. That mean if you write a module, you need override theme too. I think, you can define method **process** of element **select**. Same with my problem is [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212321/allow-fapi-checkboxes-to-specify-some-options-as-disabled).

Comment: THEME_form_select_options() was named incorrectly. I have updated my code.

Comment: Your way is correctly. I just note, if you just write in your module. You can write once use everywhere(when you change theme, you don't need copy and override function THEME_select() ).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer in this case use a single line of jQuery.

```
$("select option:first-child").attr("disabled", "true");
```

It adds the disabled attribute :

```
<option value="disabled_options" disabled="disabled">-- choice : --</option>
```

I would have preferred to do it with formApi but I think this is too much code for a basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

I took [Sébastien Gicquel](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/299709) answer and tweaked it a little, so you can define disabled options when building form.

It is for Drupal 10 but I think it is so simple that should work on other Drupal versions as well.

In JS file (I created small library `mymodule\forms` to customize forms) create code to disable certain options.

```
$(".select-options-disabled").each(function(){
  let selectNode = $(this);
  let optionsIdxs = selectNode.data('options-disabled').split(",");
  $.each(optionsIdxs, function(_i, idx){
    selectNode.find('option:nth-child(' + idx + ')').attr("disabled", "true");
  });
});
```

Then in any buildForm function when you want to create select with disabled options just add two attributes to it. Class `.select-options-disabled`, and `data-options-disabled` as comma seperated list of options to disable in given select. For example:

```
$form['my_options'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'select',
  '#options'       => $options,
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => ['select-options-disabled'],
    'data-options-disabled' => '1,3',
  ],
);
```

Remember to add your JS file in my case it is my library

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/forms';
```

Also keep in mind that [CSS nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector starts from 1, not 0 therefore to disable first option in select add "1" not "0" :)

Still I wish there would be better option to do this, if there is please add comment here.

Answer (score -1):

If you just set an empty array as value the option will be disabled.

```
['#options']['my disabled option'] = [];
```

this option will get the name, 'my disabled option' and will be disabled.